# Django: Set choices on form attribute MultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following django form:

```
class SpecifyColumnsForm(forms.Form):
    columns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Now, **I want to specify the choices for this `MultipleChoiceField` from `views.py`. How can I do that?**

I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
        columns_form = SpecifyColumnsForm(request.POST)
        columns_form.choices = (('somestuff', 'spam'),
                                ('otherstuff', 'eggs'),
                                ('banana', 'bar'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) itself states that

> `class MultipleChoiceField(**kwargs)¶`
>
> [...]
>
> Takes one extra required argument, choices, as for ChoiceField.

So all you  have to do is

```
cool_choices = (('somestuff', 'spam'),
                ('otherstuff', 'eggs'),
                ('banana', 'bar'))

class SpecifyColumnsForm(forms.Form):
    columns = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=cool_choices)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py you have to set:

```
choices = (('somestuff', 'spam'),
           ('otherstuff', 'eggs'),
           ('banana', 'bar'))
form.fields["columns"].choices = choices
```

This works for me, I'm just not sure if you can avoid to not set `choices`in forms.py. I think you need anyway to put it in forms.py, if this is a required argument for `MultipleChoiceField` otherwise your form might not be valid.