# How to manage post method request in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I cannot get the right data from the following POST form:

view.py

```
queryset=ExampleT.objects.filter(id=var_id).order_by('value1')
form = HiddenForm(initial={'ids': [o.id for o in queryset]})
return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

form.py

```
class HiddenForm(forms.Form):
ids = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput())
```

output:

```
<input id="id_ids_0" name="ids" type="hidden" value="10" />
<input id="id_ids_1" name="ids" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input id="id_ids_2" name="ids" type="hidden" value="2" />
```

This is the value of the request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'g2ktgFpDA5aa3BK2Baaes2nAexxKKh4Y'], u'ids': [u'1', u'2', u'10']}>
```

How can I get within an array the 3 values, possibly in the order [10, 1, 2]?

I have tried this code, but it return only one value:

```
var_for=request.POST.get('ids')
    for tmp_var in range(len(var_for)):
        print var_for[tmp_var]
```

Comment: You are using `request.POST.get()`, will only return a single value. To return a list of values, you need `request.POST.getlist('ids')`. However, it would be better to fetch the value from the form's cleaned data, as in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `form.cleaned_data` and also check for `form.is_valid()`

```
def myview(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = HiddenForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            ids = form.cleaned_data['ids']
            # ... return some sort of http response
    else:
        queryset=ExampleT.objects.filter(id=var_id).order_by('value1')
        form = HiddenForm(initial={'ids': [o.id for o in queryset]})

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: The condition `if form.is_valid():` is never working for me. Could it be the form creation from a queryset `form = HiddenForm(initial={'ids': [o.id for o in queryset]})`?

Comment: if form is invalid, then `form.errors` should tell you something

Comment: Thanks, I now see the error, but I have no idea for the reason `<ul class="errorlist"><li>ids<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 10 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: when you define a `MultipleChoiceField` you should define which are the allowed choices, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185867/django-set-choices-on-form-attribute-multiplechoicefield

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
form = HiddenForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    var_for = form.cleaned_data['ids']
```